# Javascript, search multiple words and replace by themselves. Replace only 1 of them in text if found

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I need to replace a few words on their own in tags. For example

> text text text dog text cat text text mouse.

Need to be replaced by `<b>dog</b>` or `<b>cat</b>` or `<b>mouse</b>` if match.
I needed to replace it once . If it find word *dog* means to replace the only dog in `<b>dog</ b>`. And nothing more. Even if *cat* or *mouse* will be the text.

I have code.

```
var str = "dog text cat text mouse",
    reg = /dog|cat|mouse/;
str = str.replace(reg, '<b>dog</b>').
```

Sorry, this only replace any of matched with `<b>dog</b>`.
Help me , please.

Comment: What should `dog dog dog` become? `<b>dog</b> <b>dog</b> <b>dog</b>`?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `g` flag to make a global search instead of just replacing the first occurance.

Use parentheses in the regular expression to catch the match, and use `$1` in the replacement to use what you caught.

```
var str = "dog text cat text mouse";
var reg = /(dog|cat|mouse)/g;
str = str.replace(reg, '<b>$1</b>')
```